# Python says that whatever variable I want to give a number is Literal and can't print it

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

so I'm new to Python and I'm learning from the book "Python for Everybody", I'm currently in Chapter 3 and I have to do an assignment. I'm supposed to give a value to numbers 1 through 7, where 1 is Monday, 2 is Tuesday...7 is Sunday. So I enter the following code, but the program says it can't print something literal and point at 1:

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Sincerely,
Ana Baird

[image: Conditional Statements If in Python]

Comment: Please put code directly in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Few mistakes here:

1. You need to use string literal `1 = "Monday"` instead of just `1 = Monday`. Otherwise `Monday` should be a variable declared before.
2. You can't assign string literal to a number and vice versa. But you can assign both numbers and literals to variables:

```py
monday = "Monday"
day_of_week = 1
```

For this exercise you can remove everything before line with `input('...')`.

P.S. Didn't find this exercise in a book. Would be better to see exact task to not guess.
P.P.S. Good practice - to keep code here, not screenshot.